# Remove transparent line from CSS code

Tags: html, css

I tried to implement this CSS code:

```
.camera_caption {
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 263px;
    padding-left: 365px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 717px;
    /*padding: 10px 20% 10px 10px;*/
    padding: 0px 10% 10px 20%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: normal 14px/24px 'Roboto';
    color: #fff;
    right: -119px;
}
.camera_caption:before,
.camera_caption:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    left: -15%;
    z-index: -1;
    /*background: #164185;*/
    background-color: rgba(22, 65, 133, 0.9);
}
.camera_caption:before {
    top: 0px;
    transform: skew(45deg);
}
.camera_caption:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

But I get transparent line here [image]

Can you give me some advice how I can remove this transparent line? For example how I can add new code for fix?

Comment: What browser? I don't see the issue in chrome or firefox

Comment: No "transparent line" is seen.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2j1sl6g/9 See here. I use the latest Firefox.

Comment: Yes it does appear in Mozilla but not in Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I also don't see it in Chrome. Only in latest Firefox and IE 9

Comment: Where is the html code?

Comment: Could be due to sub-pixel rendering issues. The height of pseudo element  is 50% and if the parent height is an odd number (say 501px) browsers could round down the 50% value to the nearest integer (and becomes 250px). So, the two pseudo-elements could leave a 1px gap in between (because 2*250px is only 500px) but can't say for sure without seeing your HTML.

Comment: Can you the HTML code in Firebug?

Comment: See the live version here https://disnalogic.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.camera_caption::before, .camera_caption::after {
  height: 50.04%; 
}
```

Comment: Looks like this fix is working. Is this the best solution? looks like a quick workaround to me?

Comment: Code ain't simple, not sure what else to try here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries.

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 1182px) {

      /* Write new positioning css for elements here */

   }
```

Looks like you have problem below 1183px width.
Take it as a break point and rewrite positioning CSS.